# How do configure front page static articles for Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm still pretty new to Joomla and I'm familar with adding custom HTML modules in various positions. I'm also familar with setting up the blog layout for the front page with leading articles, intro articles, etc. However I have a case where I would like to have a image slideshow with a static lead article under that, with 3 intro articles (one in each column), with all new articles listed below this hortizontally instead of being added to the top of the list. Is this possible and if so how can it be done?

see [The R.I.P. Files](http://www.theripfiles.tv/index.php)

Thank you
Jim

Answer (score 0):

For the slide show +static article I would either put it in a module in a position  or put it inside a lead article. In terms of keeping your one article at the top one trick is to give it an order of -1. Another would be to manually maintain the order you want and use order by order.